# Trying To Install Libnotify

Tags: sh, automake

When I run `sudo sh autogen.sh` I get this output:

```
Processing ./configure.ac
Running gtkdocize...
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory ``.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=no-portability -I m4 ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing --warnings=no-portability
configure.ac:75: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:69: installing 'build-aux/missing'
docs/reference/Makefile.am:73: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
libnotify/Makefile.am:85: error: HAVE_INTROSPECTION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
libnotify/Makefile.am:120: error: HAVE_INTROSPECTION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
libnotify/Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
tests/Makefile.am:1: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
tools/Makefile.am:10: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Now I get that I can install it with `sudo apt-get install libnotify4` but I need to get the latest version because an install of the Nuvola Apps Runtime requires it.

Comment: Rather than build libnotify from source, would it be better/easier to `sudo apt-get install libnotify4`?

Comment: It is but for some reason I have to get the latest version and build it from the source

Comment: Why are you running `autogen.sh` as super-user? That's asking for trouble. You can configure and build source code bundles (with a few exceptions) as a regular user.

Comment: Which version of libnotify are you trying to install? What's your Ubuntu release and what's the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1}\t${Package}\t${Version}\n' autoconf\* automake\* | sed -ne 's/^i\t//p'`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to build from source. While there are reasons to do this - for example, if you need to use cutting-edge features that have not been released yet, in general it's not the ideal way to install software.

Installing from source means you'll have to manually look out for updates (including security updates).

You might prefer to install with the system package manager, which installs a bundle that's been tested against your version of Ubuntu and will be checked for updates by the OS.

As Charles Green mentioned, you can do this with `sudo apt-get install libnotify4`.

Comment: Yeah the thing is I am trying to install the Nuvola Apps Runtime but when I run the command `python3 ./waf configure` I get this output: 
`Checking for 'libnotify'                      : not found` and I don't  exactly get why. I ran `sudo apt-get install libnotify4` and it installed perfectly fine but it still shows that.